# Unknown attribute onItemSelected/onCheckedChanged

Tags: android, xml, mvvm, android-databinding

I created SwitchCompat and added `android:onCheckedChanged`. everything works fine, but Android Studio marks this attribute as warning with 
description.

> Unknown attribute android:onCheckedChanged.

The same case is with AppCompatSpinner with `android:onItemSelected`.

Why Android Studio displaying this warning? My Android Studio version is 3.5.1

[screenshot with warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAHee.png)

Comment: Post your code please dude

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I don't know why it marks it as a warning. It seems strange like it can cause a crash or some other anomaly. But it works fine, I am receiving the boolean value in my ViewModel.

Answer (score 3):

That is because SwitchCompat actually does not have such attribute (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat#xml-attributes_1)), so you can't assign the listener in the XML. Try implementing an onClickListener instead or assign the OnCheckedChanged listener outside of XML, such as:

```
  final SwitchCompat switchButton = (SwitchCompat) view.findViewById(R.id.switch_button);
  switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      //do stuff
    }
  });
```

**Edit:**
You can also get the switch button from the dataBinding object in java code by calling binding.switch_button which returns the SwitchButton directly.

Comment: so its no way to do it with databinding? 
it's weird because it works correctly, all my problem in this case, that Android Studio marks it as warning

Comment: @AndroidBoy Sorry for the late reply, I was not aware of this back then, but in java code you can actually call binding.viewId to get a component with that id. Not sure if it would help you cause, just something that has been missing in my original answer.

Comment: Can vouch for it working fine, I just add a suppression in the xml file to silence Lint on this. `That is because SwitchCompat actually does not have such attribute`, but it inherits from a CompoundButton, why would it not?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a code for my CheckBox
Try somethiing like this in your java file etc. remeber to call the and asign the variable of the check box or wich ever

Your problem is that AS does not recognize the attribute IN the XML try Hardcoding the ifchecked etc in the coding side, as you call the attribute AS finds that but it is a "custom" attribute if you understand wha I am saying

```
 CheckBox chk=findViewById(R.id.chk1);
            if (chk.isChecked()) {
                Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder();
                builder.scheme("https")
                        .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
                        .appendPath("files-upload-ruben.asp")
                        .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Category", Item)
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientName", Item2)
                        .appendQueryParameter("NoEmail", "Yes");
                myURL=builder.build().toString();
            } else {
                Uri.Builder builder4=new Uri.Builder();
                builder4.scheme("https")
                        .authority("URL)
                        .appendPath("CheckBox chk=findViewById(R.id.chk1);
            if (chk.isChecked()) {
                Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder();
                builder.scheme("https")
                        .authority("www.FakeSite.co.za")
                        .appendPath("ServerFile.asp")
                        .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Category", Item)
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientName", Item2)
                        .appendQueryParameter("NoEmail", "Yes");
                myURL=builder.build().toString();
            } else {
                Uri.Builder builder4=new Uri.Builder();
                builder4.scheme("https")
                        .authority("www.fakeSite.co.za")
                        .appendPath("ServerFile.asp")
                        .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Category", Item)
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientName", Item2)
                        .appendQueryParameter("NoEmail", "");
                myURL=builder4.build().toString();")
                        .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                    .appendQueryParameter("Category", Item)
                    .appendQueryParameter("ClientName", Item2)
                    .appendQueryParameter("NoEmail", "");
            myURL=builder4.build().toString();
```