# SwitchCompat onClick not firing from XML layout

Tags: android

We use databinding in out project thus not instantiating controls in code, but doing that within the layout xml. We've done that throughout the app with all UI controls and it works great.
Problem is that I've now added a `SwitchCompat` control to my layout. It only has `onClick` (not firing) and it doesn't have `onCheckedChange` which you would expect from a SwitchCompat, right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="music.queue_ui.list.QueueListViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.toggleHeader()}" />
</layout>
```

The `toggleHeader` never get called :-(

```
package music.queue_ui.list

import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable


class QueueListViewModel(
) : ViewModel() {

    private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

    fun toggleHeader() {
        // This never gets hit by SwitchCompat `onClick`. 
        // Why??????
        Toast.makeText(
            context, "SwitchCompat Clicked",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        disposables.clear()
    }
}
```

Anyone one knows of a good solution?

Comment: Can you try this: android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.toggleHeader()}" ?

Comment: onClick lambda must conform to the onClick signature

Comment: @ChintanSoni Now I can see that the I was missing the `view` there, but now the databinding impl file build fails using the onClick(view) signature..

Comment: @ChintanSoni I've updated the signature and it builds fine but still doesn't fire:
android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.toggleHeader(v)}"

Comment: My toggleHeader function looks like this now: fun toggleHeader(view: View) {
        if (view is SwitchCompat) {
            if (view.isChecked) {
                // Do something
            } 
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
android:onCheckedChanged="@{(v,checked)->viewModel.toggleHeader(checked)}"
```

Comment: Makes great sense. Tried it though and still doesn't fire...
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{(v, checked) -> viewModel.toggleHeader(checked)}" />

Comment: When writing the above code, the intelisense doesn't have the `onCheckedChanged` at all, but it doesn't complain when I manually add it. Strange.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you set binding `viewModel` variable in your fragment/activity?

Comment: I set it up at the layout xml as we do throughout the app. When clicking go to declaration on the `viewModel.toggleHeader` it jumps to the viewmodel function as it should, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Not exactly. Can you share your activity/fragment code where you use this layout?

Comment: The architecture is not so easy to demonstrate using much RXJava, Usecases and Behaviors, so that'll be too much to explain here. I found this post though which explains that assigning the CheckedChange in XML is not possible for the SwitchCompat UI component. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521641/1545435

Comment: Works fine to me. I've created a sample here: https://github.com/sdex/StackOverflowSamples/tree/main/app/src/main/java/dev/sdex/stackoverflow/q67077309

Comment: Well, as you suggested, the problem was related to propper binding of this class which is a header item in a RecyclerView. I rearranged and now the suggested `onCheckedChanged` fires the event fine. Thanks for your help :-)